# Symfony2 Elfinder doesn't load with Tinymce

Tags: javascript, symfony, tinymce, elfinder

Since Sunday, I have followed the documentation of symfony2 about the CMF Media Bundle ([here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/media/index.html)) in purpose to download pictures and be able to exploit them, I've picked different bundles :

```
 #composer.json
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    #...
    "components/jquery": "^2.2",
    "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "^0.4.0",
    "symfony-cmf/media-bundle": "^1.2",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.4",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~4",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.2.*"
```

(I began the project with symfony 3.0, and just downgrade to 2.8 without any proper installation, but the one given just by composer update).

And here is the configuration given in the documentation with few modifications :

```
# app/config/config.yml
# Cmf Media
cmf_media:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled:         true
            manager_name:    ~
            media_basepath:  /cms/media
            media_class:     Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Media
            file_class:      Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\File
            directory_class: Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Directory
            image_class:     Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\MediaBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Image
            event_listeners:
                stream_rewind:    true
                image_dimensions: true
                imagine_cache:    auto

# Liip imagine
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        image_upload_thumbnail:
            data_loader: cmf_media_doctrine_phpcr
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
        elfinder_thumbnail:
            data_loader: cmf_media_doctrine_phpcr
            quality: 85
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [48, 48], mode: inset }

# Elfinder
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: tinymce4 # ckeditor, other options are tinymce, tinymce4, fm_tinymce,  form, simple, custom
            tinymce_popup_path: "asset[bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js]"
            fullscreen: false # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
           connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:
                    uploads:
                        show_hidden: false # defaults to false, hide files that
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 2M
        form:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: form # other choices are tinymce or simple, and form
            fullscreen: false # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
            connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                    uploads:
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 2M

# doctrine phpcr
doctrine_phpcr:
    odm:
        auto_mapping: true
    session:
        backend:
            type: doctrinedbal
            logging: true
            profiling: true
        workspace: default
        username: ******
        password: ******

# tinymce
stfalcon_tinymce:
    include_jquery: false
    tinymce_jquery: true
    selector: ".tinymce"
    base_url: %base_url%
    tinymce_buttons:
        stfalcon: # Id of the first button
            title: "Stfalcon"
            image: "http://stfalcon.com/favicon.ico"
    theme:
        simple: ~
        advanced:
            entity_encoding: "raw"
            file_browser_callback : elFinderBrowser
            plugins:
                - "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak"
                - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
                - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
                - "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            file_browser_callback : elFinderBrowser
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | example"
            image_advtab: true
            templates:
                - {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'}
                - {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
        # BBCode tag compatible theme (see http://www.bbcode.org/reference.php)
        bbcode:
            plugins: ["bbcode, code, link, preview"]
            menubar: false
            toolbar1: "bold,italic,underline,undo,redo,link,unlink,removeformat,cleanup,code,preview"
```

Here is the javascript used in the html.twig file :

```
{% javascripts
    '@jquery'
    '@file_browser' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{{ tinymce_init() }}
```

and the settings :

```
assets:
    jquery:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
    file_browser:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/fmelfinder/js/elfinder.min.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/fmelfinder/js/tinymce.js'
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/stfalcontinymce/js/init.jquery.js'
```

and I get this result : [image]

When I expect something like that (obtain from `http://localhost/app-dev.php/elfinder` which is the default url to test and use the elfinder bundle) :

[image]

Where did I fail to configure the elfinder and tinymce's parameters ?
Should I do a proper install of the 2.8 version of symfony2 ?

**Edit 1 :** 
Here is the routing file :

```
...
cmf_media_file:
    resource: "@CmfMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/file.xml"

cmf_media_image:
    resource: "@CmfMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/image.xml"

_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

elfinder:
     resource: "@FMElfinderBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Comment: After few research, I use the command line : `doctrine:phpcr:repository:init` which allowed me to bypass the last problem. But now I've this one : `Unable to open "default folder".
Folder not found.`

Comment: Hi. did you find any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Symfony3 with the Elfinder bundle and TinyMCE4 (although I'm not using Symfony CMF).  What it boiled down to for me was that the the ELFinder window was not loading the javascript assets that create the finder window.  If you debug or look at source of the html created in the window, you'll see several javascript files that need to load to create the window. The biggest problem I found was that i did not have the `component-dir` directive in my composer.json config node. To get this to work properly, I had to:

**Add the component-dir directive to my composer.json file:**

```
//composer.json
{
    ...
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    },
    ...
}
```

**Create the assets directory in the web root**

> mkdir web/assets

**Install assets**

> php bin/console assets:install

or if symlinking assets

> php bin/console assets:install --symlink

Clear cache and go for it.  Hope this works for you as well.  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you ! It was one of the problem, but it doesn't solve anything yet : point is that the `enabled:         true` don't link to link to the database. I'll add the routing in my post.